# Sort for HashMap<String, String> in Android

Tags: java, android, collections

I have a HashMap and I need sort him by key. What must I do? If you will give me example than I will be glad. Thank you for, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Pick an implementation of [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (for example [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)), and :

- If your keys implement `Comparable` use use the copy-constructor (`new TreeMap(existingMap)`) to put your existing map elements to the sorted map.
- If your keys are not comparable, create the `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` and then use `treeMap.addAll(existingMap)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.lang.TreeMap` instead